# Intersectionpoints 3D => Intersection of path3 with Bezier triangle is not yet implemented

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I am using Asymptote version 2.80 on a W10 PC.
I try to re-use an old (2019) code to plot the intersection of a sphere with a cone.
The 2019 generated drawing is joined.
?[image: original result]

I did that in 2019, but when I now compile I get following error message :

*if(s.triangular) abort(triangular); ^ C:\Program Files\Asymptote2_80/three_surface.asy: 1296.25: Intersection of path3 with Bezier triangle is not yet implemented.*

The code is following -- All construction steps are drawn.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{asy} 
    size(10cm);
    import graph3;
    currentprojection=orthographic((5,1,2),up=Z);

    settings.render=4;      // Pose pb si =0 : Le plan devant la sphere est absent
    settings.prc=false;

    currentlight=Viewport;
    real k=1;

    path3 Directrice = rotate(30,Y)*unitcircle3;
    draw(Directrice,orange);

    triple S=(0,-1.5,2);
    draw(Label ("S",green),S);
    
    path3 Directrice = rotate(60,-Y)*unitcircle3;
    path3 Directrice = shift(1.5,0,0)*Directrice;
    
    triple P1 = relpoint(Directrice,0);
    triple P2 = relpoint(Directrice,0.25);
    triple P3 = relpoint(Directrice,0.5);
    triple P4 = relpoint(Directrice,0.75);
    
    // t.x => point m de D -- t.y => facteur k 
    triple f(pair t) {
    triple Point =relpoint(Directrice,t.x);
    real X= S.x+t.y*(Point.x-S.x);
    real Y= S.y+t.y*(Point.y-S.y);
    real Z= S.z+t.y*(Point.z-S.z);
    //dot((X,Y,Z),orange);
    return (X,Y,Z);
    }
    
    surface s1=surface(f,(0,0),(1,1),36,36,Spline);
    draw(s1,orange+opacity(.7));
    
    surface sph=shift(0,0,0)*scale3(1)*unitsphere;
    draw(sph,blue);
    
    limits((0,0,0),(k+2,k+2,k+2));
    xaxis3("$x$",Arrow3);
    yaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
    zaxis3("$z$",Arrow3);
    
    draw(Directrice,red);
    
    dot(Directrice^^S,orange);
    
    // size(p) = C'est le nombre de points qui définissent le path p
    for(int i=0; i<size(Directrice);++i) {
         draw(point(Directrice,i)--S,dashed);
    }

/////// INTERSECTION -- On recherche les points d'intersection de 100 segments [Sm] avec la sphère.
    triple[][] inter;
    path3 ch1,ch2;
    int n=100;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        path3 p=S--relpoint(Directrice,i/n);
        inter.push(intersectionpoints(p,sph,0.001));
        draw(p,yellow);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<inter.length; ++i){
        if (inter[i].length!=0){
            ch1=ch1..inter[i][0]; 
            dot(inter[i][0],2bp+green);
        }
        if(inter[i].length==2){
        ch2=ch2..inter[i][1]; 
        dot(inter[i][1],2bp+red);}
    }
draw(ch1..cycle,1bp+green);
draw(ch2..cycle,1bp+red);

// Il reste à fermer la boucle : du 1er point de construction de ch1 au 1er point de construction ce ch2, et idem pour le dernier point

draw(point(ch1,0)..point(ch2,0),5bp+orange );
draw(point(ch1,(size(ch1)-1) )..point(ch2,(size(ch2)-1) ) ,5bp+orange    );
    
    \end{asy}
    \caption{Projection gnomonique 3D \label{Fig_Proj_Gnomo_3D} }
\end{figure}
```

What are the intersectionpoints (between what and what) I can ask to be retuned

The idea is to draw the gnomonic projection of a terrestrial parralel on a plane tangent to north pole, then to a plane tangent to equator , then to a plane tangent  at 50 degre latitude North : any solution without using "intersectionpoints" is welcome

Comment: I have no idea about the error. I think the figure is simple. If you give a description in details, then maybe the figure can be drawn with shorter code

Comment: I finally managed to make it work again using asymptote 2.61 with gs 9.23.

Comment: What I try to achieve is following : I have a sphere and a cone. The cone can have any orientation in regards to the sphere with the restriction that the sphere is cut by the cone so that the cutted part of the sphere stays "inside" the cone, and the I would like to draw the countour of the cutted srface surface of the sphere. Hope is clear enough

Comment: The result, if the center of the cone is the center of the sphere and if the cone's axis is the Z axis shows the gnomonic projection of a parallel, like in this figure, withich also shows the projection of a meridian. (unable to add a picture in this comment)